# How to delete all messages from a channel with Discord bot

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

What I want to do is when the specified command "m!clear" is sent, the bot will delete all messages in that channel (or a specific amount). I already have  `if message.content.startswith('m!clear):` But I don't know what to do for the next part.

Comment: _But I don't know what to do for the next part._ Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to, whenever m!clear is said, I delete all or a set number of messages. I am not sure of the code to do this.

Comment: _I am not sure of the code to do this._ Alright, so how do you usually solve problems? Have you tried breaking down the task on paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it wont be quite good to delete all the messages. i can share you a code for deleting a specific number of messages

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True) 
#only those with the permission to manage messages can use this command

async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
    await ctx.send(f"{amount} message(s) got deleted")
```

to use this, use [command] [value]
i.e : clear 10